# php function to return list of users in database table

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I am trying to get the list of all the users in my table in a function then return the list to a php page. I think I am missing some small detail because i can not get anything returned. I am new to OOP and PDO, so I am having trouble pin pointing the problem.

Here is the function

```
public function get_users() {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ");

    try{
                    $results = array();
        $query->execute();
        while($rows = $query->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $results[] = $rows;
                }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $results;

}
```

And in the page:

```
$user_list  = $users->get_users();
foreach ($user_list as $ul) {
    echo $ul['username'];
}
```

Any pointers would be a great help. Thank you

Comment: `return $results;` not `return $results[];`

Comment: It would also be a good idea to initialise `$results = array();` before your `while` loop

Comment: I am not getting any errors no, and i added [] just to try, without was also not working. I have tried quite a few different ways of doing this

Comment: @MarkBaker Just a quick question. Is it necessary to use prepared statements even if no user input/php variables are inserted in the SQL?

Comment: It's not _necessary_, but there's no harm in being consistent.

Comment: Get into the habit of always using prepared statements, that way you'll never forget to use a prepared statement when you do need it, and switching between prepared/unprepared in the same application looks messy and amateurish; there are also some potential benefits with query caching on the database if you use prepared statements

Comment: Your `while` loop can be replaced with just calling `$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: PDO doesn't have a `fetch_assoc` method, how could you not be getting an error for that?

Comment: Switch on your error reporting!

Comment: I'm not sure why am getting no errors, I tried using just fetch and tired fetchAll. I found fetch_assoc on a google search, so i tried it as well. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
    while($rows = $query->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $results[] = $rows;
            }
```

to:

```
    while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $results[] = $rows;
            }
```

or:

```
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

There is no `fetch_assoc` method in PDO, that's mysqli.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's no need to prepare that statement.  There aren't any bound parameters, so it doesn't make sense (IMHO). You *can* do it, but since you won't be running the query multiple times there no benefit.

Second of all, you can set `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` at instantiation or at fetch.  Much nicer, again IMHO.

Finally, if you use [`\PDOStatment::fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), you're already returning an array, so no need to build that array.

Your new, simpler function would look like this (untested):

```
public function get_users()
{
    try {
        return $this->db
            ->query("SELECT * FROM `users`")
            ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the additional backslashes?

Comment: That relates to PHP namespaces.  PDO is in the global namespace, so it should always be prefixed by a backslash.  While it doesn't matter in the cases when your class or functions aren't namespaced, it's a best practice and a good habit to adopt: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

Comment: Thanks. I am just trying to keep consistency and practice using PDO, as this is my first project using it, i have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

you have forgaten to initialize `$results` as array and return `$results` not `$results[]`

```
public function get_users() {

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ");
    $results=array();
    try{
        $query->execute();
        while($rows = $query->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $results[] = $rows;
                }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $results;//correct your return also

}
```

Comment: While it's bad practice to depend on it, PHP will initialize the variable as an array when you do `$results[] = something;`

Comment: Ya that is also something i tried, since posting. I will edit my post